# Creating a filename for an opened file descriptor

Tags: macos, c, file-descriptors

I have a file on the filesystem. I'm opening the file with the `open(2)` function to get the file descriptor to that file.

Now I remove the file. But I still have the file descriptor, so I can read and write to that file without problems, because the filesystem will not remove the file allocation of my file until last file descriptor is closed.

But after I remove the file, and while I still hold the file descriptor, can I somehow re-create (re-bind) the filename to that file descriptor? So the file would appear again on the filesystem, so it won't be removed when I close the file descriptor? (all I have is an opened file descriptor and nothing else).

I'm mostly interested if this can be done on macOS (on Linux/glibc it seems to be possible to do by using `linkat` with the `AT_EMPTY_PATH` flag).

Answer (score 1):

As you mention, [`linkat` on Linux](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/link.2.html) allows this to be done using `AT_EMPTY_PATH`, but only for privileged processes. (There’s some discrepancy between the man page and the current implementation; see [the commit introducing “`flink`”](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=f0cc6ffb8ce8961db587e5072168cac0cbc25f05) and [the commit reverting it](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=f0cc6ffb8ce8961db587e5072168cac0cbc25f05) for details.) It can also be done through `/proc`.

The [macOS version of `linkat`](https://keith.github.io/xcode-man-pages/link.2.html) doesn’t support this, and I’m not aware of any other way of achieving this.